# Is the Doubles Long Service Line active during a Singles match?

Tags: rules, badminton, serve

What are the rules during serving with respect to the Doubles Long Service Line?
Can I serve beyond that in a Doubles match?
In a Singles match?

[image: Badminton Court image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a Doubles match you must serve between the Short Service Line and the Doubles Long Service Line, and in a Singles match, you must serve between the Short Service Line and the Singles Long Service Line, also known as the Back Boundary Line.

There is an exception however, for Para-badminton wheelchair Classes singles, the Doubles Long Service Line is used, with the Doubles Sideline and only half the court.

This information is from [BWF Section 1 - Laws of Badminton](http://www.worldbadminton.com/rules/index.html).